# Laravel pass array to view using with

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with `with` method in `view` function. I would like to pass data variable and status. I do that:

```
return view('user.blogsettings')
->with(array('data' => $this->_data, 'status' => 'Save'));
```

Data item from array works ok, but status is not

```
 @if (session('status'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session('status') }}
                </div>
 @endif
```

There is no message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with()` method on `View` doesn't send to session, it passes it as variable to the view so you can access it as `$status` instead of `session('status')`

If you want to [explicitly add it to session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#storing-data) then use `session(['status' => 'Save'])` and this would be flashed to the session for the ongoing request.
You may check Laravel's doc [Passing Data to view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views) for further information

I hope this is useful.